# Share objects in next js / react between pages

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js

How can I share the `socket.io` **Connection** object between all pages in my Next.js application, so the connection is established when entering the page, but is not closed and opened again when switching pages.

Currently I open the connection in `componentDidMount()` of each page.

Comment: Which version of Next.js are you using. Maybe trying to use [`_app.js`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app) might help.

Comment: @bennygenel Is it bad practice to save the objects in window.varname in the _app.js and access the objects saved there in the components? Or is it possible to pass a instance to every page in the _app.js (I tried it but I did not really manage it)

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't be needing to use window variables. I'm updating with-socket-io example on nextj. I will be making a pull request. I'll update you here when it finishes.

Comment: you can check my PR [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/4644)